# MySQL Understanding Basic Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to understand basic MySQL joins.

Basically I've got 2 tables one with a customer first name and address id in it and another with the actual address.

Rather than just displaying the customer name and an address id I want it to display the customer name and the actual address.

My basic select statement is like this:

```
SELECT firstName, addressId FROM Customer
```

It will display something like this:

```
firstName   addressId
---------------------
Bob         56
```

Rather than than I would like to join the addressId with an actual address in another table

Like this:

```
firstName    address
----------------------------------
Bob          45 Somewhere street
```

Is there anyone who can show me the best way to achieve this?

Also can anyone recommend a good tutorial for joins?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp - W3Schools, fairly basic, but will set you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is inner join,
This is the simplest, most understood Join and is the most common. This query will return all of the records in the left table (Customer) that have a matching record in the right table (address). This Join is written as follows:

```
 SELECT firstName, address FROM Customer 
 INNER JOIN address ON Customer.addressId=address.addressId
```

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fa21/1)

Sample Output :

```
FIRSTNAME       ADDRESS
  Bob       45 Somewhere street
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  a.name, b.address
FROM    Customer a INNER JOIN AddressList b on a.addressID = b.addressID
```

To learn more about joins, see the article below,

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @swapnesh That linked page should die in flames. It's a very poor representation of joins. It is a very good representation of Unions, Intersections and Set Differences though.

Comment: @ypercube Its better to have something than nothing..its a pictorial representation so i thought it would be great to read..but its been more if u suggest some another, because i too really struggle with the joins ..i.e upvoted the answer..googled a lot but may be my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Put the same 'addressid' in both the name and address tables then join the two as:

```
select name, address from customer join addresses 
on customer.addressid = addresses.addressid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both tables have an address id, you could use

```
SELECT firstname, address, from table1 JOIN table2 
ON table1.addressid = table2.addressid
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be:

```
SELECT firstName, address FROM Address As A 
INNER JOIN Customer as C ON C.addressId=A.addressId
```

### [Visual Representation of JOINS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you have following tables:

```
Customer(ID, FName, LName, AddressID)
Address(AddressID, Streeet, HNUmber, City)
```

This will display customers address instead of AddressID:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.Fname, c.LName, a.Street, a.HNumber, a.City
FROM Customer c, Address a
WHERE
  c.AddressID = a.AddressID
```