# How to join hierarchical table in MySQL (table joins other table that joins other table that joins other table)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables, tb_item, tb_branch, tb_department, tb_division.

[image: database design]

As you can see:

- tb_division is under tb_department
- tb_department is under branch
- tb_branch has no superior

for example if I want to retrieve item_id 1 or 2 or 3 then this should be the result

[image: desired result]

If I want to retrieve item_id 2 then it will show the department and branch.
**My problem is that I can nested join them if if I know the item is related to a specific table but in this case since tb_item can be related to tb_division or tb_department and tb_branch I don't know what query should I formulate**.

Changing the database design is not an option since this design is already implemented.

Comment: learn about joins

Comment: See [SQL - Using Joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Understanding Basic Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138693/mysql-understanding-basic-joins)

Comment: Guys i know how to use join. My main problem here is since the tb_item can be related to either of the 3 table i dont know what query should be used for that

Comment: @Juz it can be done using left join

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile: please do not add [solved] title hacks here. We don't do that, and it just creates work for volunteer editors to fix it up.

Comment: point noted @halfer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name1 JOIN table-name2 
    ON column-name1 = column-name2
 WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind guys. I managed to solved it myself. been struggling since I thought I need to do tons of subqueries. Thanks for the answers tho.

```
SELECT
   i.item_id,
   dv.division_name,
   COALESCE(dept.department_name, dept2.department_name) AS department_name,
   COALESCE(br.branch_name, br2.branch_name, br3.branch_name) AS branch_name 
FROM
   tb_item AS i 
   LEFT JOIN
      tb_division AS dv 
      ON i.division_id = dv.division_id 
   LEFT JOIN
      tb_department AS dept2 
      ON dv.department_id = dept2.department_id 
   LEFT JOIN
      tb_branch AS br2 
      ON dept2.branch_id = br2.branch_id 
   LEFT JOIN
      tb_department AS dept 
      ON i.department_id = dept.department_id 
   LEFT JOIN
      tb_branch AS br3 
      ON dept.branch_id = br3.branch_id 
   LEFT JOIN
      tb_branch AS br 
      ON i.branch_id = br.branch_id
```