# Get count of items that exist inside string column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that looks like

**Items**

- id (int)
- name (varchar)
- category_ids (varchar)

In category_ids there is string that can be "", "1,3,7" or "4" or "1,6, 9" - this numbers are category ids

**Categories**

- id (int)
- name (varchar)

I want to know how many items are in each category

Comment: You can use FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: Would've been so much easier if you just had a many to many table for items & categories.

Comment: Then you should, if at all possible, fix your _broken_ system first; this should be properly _normalized_, instead of being stored as a comma-separated string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Understanding Basic Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138693/mysql-understanding-basic-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching for solution I need to say two things

1) This task can be solved by using function called FIND_IN_SET() function (as Suresh Kamrushi suggested)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items WHERE FIND_IN_SET("1",category_ids)
```

2) It is better not to use this kind of table linking structure - think about making you database normalized using many to many relationship table